# OpenGL ES fetch screen as texture

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want to fetch back my Sceen as texure like this:

```
 //Get the rendered Image as Texure
 glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,pixelsRenderedImage);

 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

 glCopyTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA,0,0,width,height,0);
```

But the Texture stays Black.
Does anyone have a Idea how to do this without using FBO's ?

Everything works fine on PC but on mobile phone the screen stays black.

Comment: Where exactly are you calling this?

Comment: AFTER the draw routine.

Comment: How exactly is this a Qt issue?

Comment: You'll need to do this at the end of the draw routine. It definitely needs to be called from the rendering thread, and it needs to be before the buffers are swapped, which implicitly or explicitly happens at the end of drawing, depending on what classes you use for your OpenGL rendering.

Comment: Size = 2^n Limitation?

Comment: Try using glReadPixels to read the back buffer into a ByteBuffer, then upload to a texture.

Comment: @samgak I don't think that's any easier, and definitely less efficient.

Comment: Should i render to framebuffer and then Display back?